# Can you compound filter examples?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can you guys give me some examples or links regarding next task:

```
var companies = [{
        members: [{
                name: 'John'
            },
            {
                name: 'Victor'
            },
            {
                name: 'Roan'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        members: [{
                name: 'John'
            },
            {
                name: 'Roan'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In

```
<input type='text'>
```

When I type "John and Victor" - I want to get companies[0] object

When I type "John and  not Victor" - I want to get companies[1] object

The QUESTION is how to parse text and make it understand where is AND and NOT??
Hope I explained good.
Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Nobody will help you if you don't explain what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function to fine names and not names. You can filter array by yourself.

```
    function searchCompanies(text) {
        var nameand = [],
            namesNot = [];
        text = text.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); //remove multiple whitespace
        var words = text.split(' ');
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            var word = words[i].toLowerCase();
            if (i == 0)
                text.push(words[i]);
            else if (word != 'and' && word != 'not') {
                if (words[i - 1].toLowerCase() != 'not')
                    text.push(words[i]);
                else
                    namesNot.push(words[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: understood. thanks. I thought there are some libs for it. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You want to parse text and run code based on it. That can get tricky, so the goal is to narrow down the rules of the system to be as simple as possible.

In this case, one problem is that we need to distinguish a name from keywords like `and` or `not`. We could maintain a list like `const keywords = ['and', 'not']` and treat anything that is NOT in that list as a name. What about case sensitivity? Should `And` be treated as a name because it is capitalized? Capitalization would be a convenient way to distinguish names from non-names.

This is just the tip of the iceberg.

But okay, let's assume the problem is as simple as it is stated. We just want to reach the bare minimum goal. I'm going to assume that all names should be included and `not` is the only truly meaningful keyword. I will exclude all names that are preceded by `not`.

```
// Extremely naive, not suitable for production. Will get
// tricked by whitespace and other simple things.
const isName = (str) => {
    return str[0] === str[0].toUpperCase();
};

const input = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');
input.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
    const tokens = evt.target.value.split(' ');
    const names = tokens.filter((name, i, arr) => {
        return isName(name) && arr[i - 1] !== 'not';
    });
    const company = {
        members : names.map((name) => {
            return { name };
        })
    };
});
```